# Erro "class DomDocument not found" ao tentar rodar o PHPUnit

Tags: php, php-domdocument, phpunit

Ao tentar rodar o comando `phpunit` na linha de comando, recebi o seguinte erro:

> Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Isso não estava acontecendo antes. 
Lembro-me de ter removido e instalado novamente o PHP.

O que pode ocasionar esse erro, visto que `DomDocument` é uma classe nativa do PHP?

Nota: Estou usando o sistema operacional Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para instalar no Ubuntu creio que este seja o comando, se for php5.6:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

Outros linux baseados em Debian ou versões antigas do Ubuntu creio que funcione assim:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dom
```

Se for o 7.0 seria este:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

php7.1:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

A única coisa que pode mudar é se estiver usando via PPA, então vai depender de como instalou

Comment: Só faltou o php5.6 :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters pensei que o `php5-dom` se ajustava a versão "corrente" do seu php.

Comment: Nesse caso, não funciona mais. Isso aí é só se você usar o PPA que foi depreciado. Agora você instala usando php5.6-* e php7.0-*

Answer (score 3):

Algumas distribuições Linux separam a extensão DOM em outro pacote para deixar a instalação mais limpa e organizada.

Não me recordo o nome do pacote no Ubuntu, mas é algo parecido com php-xml.
Após instalar, certifique-se que a extensão esteja ativa no php.

Você pode verificar olhando pelo phpinfo();

Caso não esteja ativa, basta adicionar a extensão no seu php.ini:

```
extension=dom.so
```

Comment: É isso mesmo, é o `php-xml` que estava faltando :p

Comment: :) Veja o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor como agradecer.

Comment: @jlHertel acho que ele não está agradecendo, ele só esta provavelmente afirmando que deve ser isto mesmo, mas a questão é mais Ubuntu que PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Para quem estiver usando PHPunit, uma boa verificação além de ver se o `php-xml` está instalado e ativo, é chamar o DOMDocument após a declaração de namespace:

```
namespace SeuNameSpace\SeuNameSpace;

use DOMDocument; //<--- aqui
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```